# mootools class cannot access object but I can see it in the console

Tags: javascript, class, mootools

I cannot access an object's property.

```
console.log(object)
```

Gives me this and shows be the the "display" property is defined
[image]

But doing this returns undefined

```
console.log(object.display)
```

How can I access the display object?

Many thanks!

```
var classOne = new Class({

   myOtherFunction : function () {
       this.display = new classTwo();
   }
});

var classTwo = new Class({

    myFunction : function () {
        //does something
        this.fireEvent('customEvent');
    }

});

var classThree = new Class({
   initialize: function () {
       // THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS
       class_one.display.addEvent('customEvent', function () {
           this.doSomething();
       }.bind(this));
   }
});

class_one = new classOne();
class_three = new classThree();
```

This is not the exact code but I removed a lot of the extra stuff. Thanks!

Comment: we need to see more code.. how are you creating the class? how are you initializing it?

Comment: In theory this should work just fine. Put up an example on JsFiddle.

Comment: it can't work - at the time he creates the prototype for classThree, there is no instance of classOne to bind to (class_one is not instantiated). not to mention the display property is only created when `myOtherFunction` method is referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that stripped version is really representative:

1. `class_one` is referenced inside `classThree` without having been declared previously.
2. `display` is initialized only when `class_one.myOtherFunction` is called.

…but you should give us more code on JsFiddle to make sure you actually took representative parts.

I'd say the best thing to do is to learn more about [Javascript variables instanciation and referencing](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp) to get this right, otherwise you will keep on encountering such problems.

*PS: you should chose either `CamelCasing` or `using_underscores_for_variables`. If camelcasing (preferred), then classes should be `UpperCasedCamelCase`, variables `lowerCaseCamelCase`.*

Comment: also, this is a really weird pattern. he should look at extending or implementing classes - not instantiating across.

Comment: You are exactly right. The property was being set too late. @Dimitar What do you mean extending or implementing the classes? classOne and classTwo are part of another programmers script and I do not want to change it.

Comment: no - you don't have to - but you can copy things from prototype of another class as a mixin via the `Implements` mutator, or even extend another class via the `Extends` mutator. eg, when I want to do a class that behaves **mostly** like Request.JSONP but with a specific DSL, eg, Twitter, I declare it as `Request.Twitter = new Class({ Extends: Request.JSON ... });` and just abstract the differences and specifics it needs. it's a structuring / planning sort of decision, really.